# pytorch - GroupNorm with momentum

Tags: pytorch, torch, channel, batch-normalization, momentum

After looking at the documentation of **pytorch** I couldn't find the module of **GroupNorm** with **momentum**, there is only an implementation which doesn't use it (which is useless to me since I would want to use **AdaBN**, or **AdaGN** I should say).

Therefore my idea was to **take** the **BatchNorm** class and **extend** it with **num_groups** and override the method that actually calculate mean and variance by firstly **reshaping** the **input** and **grouping** **channels** together, so to emulate the GroupNorm behavior.

In order to do this I looked into the source code until I found a dead end in [torch.nn.functional.batch_norm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html#batch_norm). That function internally calls another function `torch.batch_norm(...)` but I couldn't find the source code for it.

Do you know where to look for that part? Or do you think there is a better way to implement this? I tried looking online for other's works, but I only found unfinished ones.

Comment: `toch.batch_norm` is a C++ function exposed to Python. Here is the C++ source: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/d1623f4cc9334ade7376b3685bb91d3071e3b418/torch/csrc/api/src/nn/modules/batchnorm.cpp

Comment: oh, thank you, but that's bad actually for me.